# ModCluster not working with wildfly 9

Tags: wildfly, mod-cluster

Wildfly not working with mod cluster below is the error_log

```
[Wed Jan 25 16:53:55.860419 2017] [core:error] [pid 4980:tid 1088] [client 192.168.1.10:64522] AH00135: Invalid method in request bela\x19\x84\x04
[Wed Jan 25 16:54:11.387227 2017] [core:error] [pid 4980:tid 1088] [client 192.168.1.10:64523] AH00135: Invalid method in request bela\x19\x84\x04
[Wed Jan 25 16:54:24.664313 2017] [core:error] [pid 4980:tid 1088] [client 192.168.1.10:64524] AH00135: Invalid method in request bela\x19\x84\x04
[Wed Jan 25 16:54:43.907621 2017] [core:error] [pid 4980:tid 1088] [client 192.168.1.10:64525] AH00135: Invalid method in request bela\x19\x84\x04
[Wed Jan 25 16:54:59.417380 2017] [core:error] [pid 4980:tid 1088] [client 192.168.1.10:64526] AH00135: Invalid method in request bela\x19\x84\x04
[Wed Jan 25 16:55:16.458689 2017] [core:error] [pid 4980:tid 1088] [client 192.168.1.10:64530] AH00135: Invalid method in request bela\x19\x84\x04
```

I am using TCP instaed of upd and server advertise is off on mod_cluster side

Comment: If you still need help, you must provide your Apache HTTP Server mod_cluster.conf and your sladalone-ha.xml (or simply mod_cluster subsystem and socket bindings XMl snippets from your Wildfly configuration). The log you posted is utterly insufficient to debug anything.

Comment: @MichalKarmBabacek i changed the advertise  to on now everything is working fine